# Bad Access Code 1: Accessing Object instance Variables

Tags: objective-c, arrays, loops

I have built up an array of objects, created from a class, I wrote before. I just wanted to access some of the class variables while looping through the array:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
       [super viewDidLoad];

       NSMutableArray *medicalCenters = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] medicalCenters];

       for (MedicalCenter *row in medicalCenters){
           NSString *latitude = row.MCLatitude;
           NSLog(@"%@", latitude);
       }
}
```

the Class File I've created look like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MedicalCenter : NSObject
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D _coordinate;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *medicalCenter;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *MCLatitude;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *MCLongitude;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)medicalCenter coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;

@end
```

Whenever I built up the `NSString *latitude = row.MCLatitude`, I got the message:
Bad_excess Code:1

But when I just list the objects in the array medicalCenters, I can see them all............
Did I miss something important?

Thanks
Sebastian

Comment: Why did you use `assign` for `MCLatitude` and `MCLongitude`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of bad memory management, `MCLatitude` and `MCLongitude` property are set with (assign), they're not being retained properly, don't know the reason you set them up as assign, no reason that I can see, so if you change them to be strong, and use setter to assign the value, it should be fine.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *MCLatitude;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *MCLongitude;
```

Comment: Thank you guys... Before I hat MCLatitude as string var, I declared it as int. And therefore had the assign property. I just changed the code and now it works perfectly fine!!! Thank you all

Comment: You should typically use `copy` instead of `strong` for NSString. You don't want your string value unexpectedly changing on you if another class also has a pointer to the same string and makes a change. Rule of thumb is that for any class that has a mutable counterpart i.e. NSMutableString, NSMutableArray, you should always `copy` them.